# How to send messages from server to web application (angular)

Tags: angular, web, django-rest-framework, background-process

Usually, An application communicates with the server by sending HTTP requests. It sends some data over a HTTP request and receives a response in turn.

But when building my application, I ran into a situation where the backend needs to send some data/message to the web application when a particular event occurs.

I read about WebPush Notifications but I dont want to use them, because it asks the user for permission to show notifications, which is kinda wierd. Even for using the WebPush API I have to request for permission to show notifications. And I dont want to rely on that because if the user clicks deny the whole application breaks which is why I was looking for other alternatives.

What alternatives are available for me?

PS: The backend I'm using is built upon Django Rest Framework

Comment: SSE, WebSockets, polling from the client.

Comment: This is more a back-end problem, then a front-end problem. JavaScript doesn't care if it's HTTP, WebSockets or WebPush. You just add code that handles one of those and you're done. What is your back-end server? Are you running a *stateless* server? Is it done in PHP, C#, Java or JavaScript? All of these things have limitations on how they handle this problem. Usually when someone asks how to resolve this problem. It's because they're running one of the back-ends that don't handle this problem well and they're looking for a hack.

Comment: @Reactgular the backend is built upon django rest framework

Answer (score 1):

One thing to consider is whether you want/need the user interface to show the changes **real time**.

If showing your data is very time sensitive you probably want to consider a **bi-directional** protocol like **websockets** and receive the server updates through this channel.

Another way to mimic a near real-time UI update is to do **polling**. The UI (on certain conditions) sets up a schedule to do periodic polling through HTTP using traditional APIs. Polling can be a good option if the data requested can be served quickly (not an expensive computation and the amount of transferred data is small) and it does not require to re-render the entire client side of the application. Polling tends to be a bandaid solution and implemented as an afterthought therefore feel extremely heavy handed (lots of data transferred and re-rendering the UIs) but if you plan on light polling it could be a good option.

If you foresee more 'real-time' like aspects of your app, you may want to introduce websockets. Be cautious on what this means to your architecture and scaling though. (There are certain architectural styles, e.g. microservices architectures, where using websockets may introduce more complexity). Browser compatibility may also be a small concern so i'd make sure you are not planning to support browsers that do not support websockets.

Comment: *polling* is generally the best answer when someone asks this question. It's the safer approach, but it does need two additional things. A resource ID to track that *thing* you are *polling* to see progress on, and the ability for the back-end to *continue work* after the Http response that started it is sent.